# What is the size of full geth ethereum node nowadays?

Tags: ethereum, go-ethereum

I'm going to setup a full Ethereum node on my PC here with geth --syncmode=full
I have to buy SSD drive for that. My question is will 1TB SSD be enough or I have to buy even more bigger (= expensive) SSD drive?

PS. I've searched over internet and didn't find recent information about it...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question as defined in the [help] guidelines.

Comment: you should be able to find more info here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need:

https://etherscan.io/chart2/chaindatasizefast

Geth has 3 modes; light, fast and full. Running fast is fine. If you want to learn more about them, [read this answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/11300/26362).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know about this graph, but this info is relevant to 'fast' syncing, as I said in my question, I'm interested in FULL import, that's why I'm asking, I had fast synced node with 256GB SSD, but now I'm in need to install a full node, and don't know which SSD I should buy, 1TB or 2TB...

Comment: AFAIK, technically both fast and full will download same size of blocks. The only difference here is, full will validate the blocks but fast will process/validate no transactions until current block.

Comment: Probably you're right, but the strange thing here is that when I did a fast sync a week ago it was enough to have a 256 GB SSD, but when I started a full sync I got 256 competely full when it downloaded ~66% of all blocks. So in this case the question is: will it require extra space when all blocks are downloaded or not? I know that while fast syncing it also require some time and disk space to perform a state tries download. Will it be a case for "full" sync and how much of disk space it will require?

Answer (score 0):

according to [this article](https://dev.to/5chdn/the-ethereum-blockchain-size-will-not-exceed-1tb-anytime-soon-58a) once Geth is done with fast sync, it switches to full sync. With a Parity Archive node approaching 2TB ([source](http://whataboutarchivenodes.5chdn.co/)) you can expect at least that much in disk-space. Running a stable node is a challenge, so you may want to look into [QuikNode](https://quiknode.io) (who can run a node in the cloud for you).

Comment: Please add more details from the links into the answer